# Is there a way to cue a Youtube video in an iframe to rounded seconds?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am using the [YouTube Iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) during playing the video i want to play something else quite simultaneously.
I get in trouble when the video is cued to a specific point, because it is not possible to get the milliseconds.

My thought was to to round down the current time by using the code below:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.CUED){
         player.seekTo(player.getCurrentTime())
    }
  }
```

But this is not working, if the video was cued to 23.4 seconds it just stays at 23.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using a newer Version of the API where player.getCurrentTime() returns a float.

Read the [docs here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#getCurrentTime)

Answer (score 0):

You can get an idea how they manage to get an accurate time from this [SO post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190604/youtube-html5-api-is-it-possible-to-get-better-time-resolution-when-polling-th) and [SO post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461176/youtube-api-seekto-in-float-seconds).

From SO post 1,

> You can specify fractions of seconds using a float number

From SO post 2, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jlmcdonald/sq2dV/1/) is a demonstration given. See below the code used.

```
 var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
        var player;
        function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw'
            });
        }
        $(window).load(function(){
            jQuery('#seek').click(function(){
                player.seekTo(parseFloat($("#seekto").val()));
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: This is nice to know, but what I need is player.getCurrentTime() which returns a float value...